# How to output multiplied user created class c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am working on an assignment overloading operators for a user-created class of rational numbers but can not output two "Rational" objects in the same line. For example:

```
std::cout<<5*10<<std::endl;
```

Outputs 50 just fine. However when I try to do,

```
std::cout<<Rational_1*Rational_2<<std::endl;
```

I receive an error. If I instead assign the value to a third rational such as

```
Rational_3=Rational_1*Rational_2;
std::cout<<Rational_3<<std::endl;
```

Then the program outputs just fine. I have brought this up to my professor but even he does not know how to fix it. Any explanation as to why this is happening would be helpful. I would like to know why this is an issue instead of just simply getting a piece of code that works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rational{
    public:
        Rational();
        Rational(int whole_number);
        Rational(int numerator_input,int denominator_input);
        friend Rational operator *(Rational rat_1, Rational rat_2);
    `   friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,Rational& output);
        void simplify();
    private:
        int numerator,denominator;
};

int main(){
    Rational r1(2,3),r2(3,4),r3;
    r3=r1*r2;
    cout<<r3<<endl;
    //cout<<r1*r2<<endl;

return 0;
}

Rational::Rational(){
    numerator=0;
    denominator=1;
}

Rational::Rational(int whole_number){
    numerator=whole_number;
    denominator=1;
}

Rational::Rational(int numerator_input,int denominator_input){
    numerator=numerator_input;
    if(denominator_input==0){
        cout<<"A rational number can not have a 0 in the denominator\n";
        exit (5);
    }
    denominator=denominator_input;
    simplify();
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,Rational& output){
    out<<output.numerator<<"/"<<output.denominator; 
    return out;
}

Rational operator *(Rational rat_1, Rational rat_2){
    Rational rat_3;
    rat_1.simplify();
    rat_2.simplify();
    rat_3.numerator=rat_1.numerator*rat_2.numerator;
    rat_3.denominator=rat_1.denominator*rat_2.denominator;
    rat_3.simplify();
    return rat_3;
}

void Rational::simplify(){
    //Flip negative sign to numerator
    for(int counter=1000000;counter>0;counter--){
        if((numerator%counter==0)&&(denominator%counter==0))
        {
            numerator=numerator/counter;
            denominator=denominator/counter;    
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: @rew Mares Use friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Rational& output); You may not bind a temporary object to a non-constant lvalue reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that takes an `int` as in your first snippet is that it takes it's argument by value.

Your overloaded `operator<<` takes a `Rational` object by reference and `Rational_1*Rational_2` returns an temporary object, temporary objects are not allowed to bind to non-const references.

Either take your argument by value or by `const&` to fix this:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Rational& output);
```

Or

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Rational output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. With your tip I got the code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the operator like

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Rational& output);
                                          ^^^^^
```

You may not bind a temporary object to a non-constant lvalue reference.